# How to fix 'ImportError: cannot import name' upon sharing global variables between files

Tags: python, python-requests

I have params on class SignIn, and want to use it on another class, but compiler says 'ImportError: cannot import name 'HEADERS_CONTENT_TYPE' from 'api.sign_in_page'

What should I do for importing global variables?

I've tried to declare variable as global before class declaration and just import them on the second class

```py
global HEADERS_CONTENT_TYPE
global TOKEN_PARAM

class SignInPage:
```

```py
from api.sign_in_page import HEADERS_CONTENT_TYPE, TOKEN_PARAM
class SignalsAddPage:

result = requests.post(url=ProjectConfigReader.SIGNALS_ENDPOINT, json=json_for_create_signal, headers={HEADERS_CONTENT_TYPE, TOKEN_PARAM})
```

I expect the new signal has been created, but
ImportError: cannot import name 'HEADERS_CONTENT_TYPE' from 'api.sign_in_page' error occurs

Comment: I guess that you're calling class attributes as _params_, if so, import the class `from foo import MyClass` and access the attribute `MyClass.myparam`

Answer (score 2):

The `global` keyword is used inside a function to set a value for a variable in the global scope. Import between modules does not require the use of the global keyword. See the FAQ below to help you.

https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules

Comment: I didn't understand your explanation. Can you write code to make it clear for me?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `global`. Just set values to variables and then you can import them. 
`global` needs to defer that name of variable inside functions scope is refer to same value that variable with same name outside of it.